# Is there a way to stop website background image multiplying

Tags: html, css

On my Website i have a background image that when I press CTRL - a few times the image eventually duplicates. I have encountered other sites with information on this problem who's solutions only stretches the image.

I have a comments section on my website so the length of my website could be huge so this method is not practical. I just want the image to remain the same even when zooming in and out because any other solution would greatly impact the look of my website.

If there is a need to see the website as a visual representation of what im trying to explain a link can be provided.

Comment: You might want to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-repeat

Comment: Hey JayC nice one man that really helped me out :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the style for the image to `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) for more info.